# Common XML file for a SharePoint farm enviroment

Tags: sharepoint-online, object-model, xml

We have create a object model DLL and display some result on based upon XML file stored on physical disk on dev box its working fine.

Issue with our production enviroment is that we have four server and we need to copy these file on four server as per current solution, but client don't want maintain 4 files and he need only one file, we have tried to place this file on a shared drive but due to IIS account permission issue not able to read.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You should play by SharePoints rules which gives you two options:

- Store the file somewhere below the SharePointRoot deployed by your WSP, but that means that the users can't change it
- Store the file in some document library, could be in Central Admin if you want to make sure that only one file is needed, an other common location is at the Content Type Hub